# How can I wait to process tuples from a Kafka Topic/Stream in Storm

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

Super new to stream processing.  Trying to see if this is possible in Core Storm, or possibly Trident.  The underlying streams are Kafka topics, if it matters, so they're reliable and even replayable.

Conceptually I have two streams, A and B:

```
A := (id, timestamp, v)
B := (id, timestamp, w)
```

I assume A and B are each in timestamp-ascending order.

I assume a Bolt reading both A and B (though I'm open to other solutions).

WLOG, for a given tuple "a" from A, to process it I need to have a corresponding tuple "b" from B, the first tuple encountered from B such that:

```
a.id == b.id
b.timestamp >= a.timestamp
```

(As such, assuming we get these events in the Bolt only one at a time, when it is processing "a", the corresponding "b" may have already appeared in the past; or may yet appear in milliseconds, months, or even never.)

For any given id, I do not mind waiting milliseconds, months, or even eternity, to pass on some modified version of the "a" event in my Storm topology.  I do however want to emit such modified events as soon as possible after all relevant information appears, and to make this whole setup scalable and redundant in all the usual pragmatic engineering ways.

How can I best implement this in Storm?

Naive thoughts I have had:

1. Keep failing to ack any "a" that doesn't have a corresponding "b" yet, or vice versa.
2. Queue up "a" and "b" style tuples in bolt memory until reciprocal events can be found, and save the Bolt state as necessary.
3. Emit problem "a" and "b" tuples on to some other stream or streams and somehow delay further processing on those tuples until an event from the reciprocal stream for the appropriate id appears.